# Каким образом в этом случае создается объект?

Tags: javascript, функции, prototype

Здесь в объекте `prototype` больше нет свойства `constructor` — там пустой объект. Однако, несмотря на это, каким-то образом эта строка `new obj.constructor` все же создает пустой объект. Как?

```js
function Constructor() { 
    this.name = 'Kira';
    this.age = 35;
    this.city = 'New-York';
}; 
Constructor.prototype = {}; //теперь prototype содержит пустой объект

let obj = new Constructor;
let obj2 = new obj.constructor;
console.log(obj2); //{}
```

Тут тоже создается объект. В консоли браузера Chrome он отображается как `String`, здесь — немного по-другому.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function User(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
User.prototype = {};

let user = new User('John');
let user2 = new user.constructor('Pete');

console.log(user2);
```

Как в этих двух случаях происходит создание объекта?

Comment: Разгадка `console.log(obj.constructor === Object) // true`

Comment: Потому что у пустого объекта тоже есть конструктор.

Comment: @Alexey Ten не совсем понимаю что вы имеете в виду. `Constructor.prototype = {}` - `prototype` был перезаписан. Соответственно, св-во `constructor` стерлось. Его нет.

Comment: @Alexey Ten  _"Потому что у пустого объекта тоже есть конструктор."_ Я так понимаю, что вы говорите про пустой объект, который был добавлен в `prototype`. Как у этого пустого объекта может быть `constructor`, если у обычных объектов не бывает `prototype` (это свойство есть только у функций), а только в `prototype` может содержаться св-во `constructor`?

Comment: @Eva , у обычных объектов `{}` есть прототип `__proto__`, в котором есть свойство `constructor` с функцией `Object()`. Если вызвать эту функцию со строкой, то будет новый объект строки.

Comment: "а только в prototype может содержаться св-во constructor" --- и ещё во всех экземплярах в свойстве `__proto__` тот же самый объект что и `prototype`. Поэтому у всех объектов есть конструктор (за исключением созданных с __proto__ null )

Comment: _При попытке получения значения свойства, если такого свойства нет = будет проверяться одноименное свойство в прототипе объекта, пока оно не будет найдено, либо пока прототипы не кончатся._